# What to use for firewall testing (port opened or not)

Tags: networking, firewall, ip, telnet

so... we know that we can test that if a port is open on the firewall with:

```
telnet SERVERIP PORT
```

..but afaik there are services that can't be tested with telnet, because ex.: telnet doesn't know that protocol that the service is using, and telnet will report that the port is closed, but in reality the service is up&running.

Q: first: was I correct about telnet? second: What to use for testing that a port is opened on a server? (so it's not blocked by a firewall) - are there any unix tools for this?

Comment: Have a look at `nmap`. It probably can do more than you will ever need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first question, maybe the service does not wait for interactive input. There could be other explanations, too. On the second,  [nmap](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/nmap1.html) can be used to test the firewall. There are many options.

Scan the first 1,000 ports (default):

```
nmap -v -A -PN hostname.domainname.com
```

Or perhaps a specific range:

```
nmap -v -A -p 10000-11000 -PN hostname.domainname.com
```

Comment: so you are saying that an: nmap -v -A -p PORTNUMBER -PN hostname.domainname.com is the best solution?

Comment: If you want to see *all* open ports on a firewall you can chuck the following at it: `nmap -v -p- <IP address or hostname>`. Of course, a lot of configurations might mean that certain services might not respond, then you'll have to get clever with the switches but there's plenty of resources.

Answer (score 2):

Your comment about telnet not being appropriate in all cases puzzled me, so I ran a quick network trace while connecting to some arbitrary ports (in this case an HTTP server and a DICOM server).

In all cases I can confirm that telnet merely opens its socket to the TCP connection but neither tries to read from it nor write to it until you explicitly type a line.

This means your TCP stack will just initiate a standard TCP handshake and the three packets involved (SYN/SYN-ACK/ACK) will be the only ones to ever travel the wire. These of course aren't specific to any application.

tl;dr It seems to me that telnet is in fact absolutely appropriate to test whether a specific port is open or not, regardless of the protocol spoken by the server listening behind it.